# FFMPEG: AV out of sync when writing a part of a video to a new file

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, timestamp

I'm developing a data preprocessing program for a computer vision project using FFMPEG and Face detection API. In this program, I need to extract the shots that contain human faces from a given input video file and output them into a new file. But when I played the output video file generated by that program, the video and audio track was out of sync. I think a possible reason is that the timestamp of video frame or audio frame is set incorrectly, but I can't fix it by myself as I'm not very familiar with FFMPEG library, Please help me solving this out-of-sync issue.

To simplify the code shown below, I have removed all face detection code and use an empty function called `faceDetect` to represent it instead.

```
// ffmpegAPI.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>

    extern "C" {
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
    #include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
    #include <libavutil/common.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
    #include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
    #include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
    #include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>

}
bool faceDetect(AVFrame *frame)
{
    /*...*/
    return true;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int64_t videoPts = 0, audioPts = 0;
    int samples_count = 0;
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL, *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    AVOutputFormat *ofmt = NULL;
    AVPacket pkt;
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    int videoindex = -1; int audioindex = -1;
    double videoTime = DBL_MAX;
    const char *in_filename, *out_filename;
    int ret, i;
    in_filename = "C:\\input.flv";//Input file name
    out_filename = "C:\\output.avi";//Output file name
    av_register_all();
    //Open input file
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_filename, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file '%s'", in_filename);
        goto end;
    }
    //Find input streams
    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to retrieve input stream information");
        goto end;
    }
    //Retrive AV stream information
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVStream *stream;
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
        stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];//Get current stream
        codec_ctx = stream->codec;//Get current stream codec
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            videoindex = i;//video stream index
        }
        else if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            audioindex = i;//audio stream index
        }
        if (videoindex == -1)//no video stream is found
        {
            printf("can't find video stream\n");
            goto end;

        }
    }
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, in_filename, 0);
    //Configure output
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create output context\n");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }
    ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;
    //Configure output streams
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {//Traversal input streams
        AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];//Get current stream
        AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);//Create a corresponding output stream
        if (!out_stream) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }
        //Copy codec from current input stream to corresponding output stream
        ret = avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context\n");
            goto end;
        }
        if (i == videoindex)//Video stream
        {
            if (out_stream->codec->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
            {
                out_stream->codec->me_range = 16;
                out_stream->codec->max_qdiff = 4;
                out_stream->codec->qmin = 10;
                out_stream->codec->qmax = 51;
                out_stream->codec->qcompress = 1;

            }
        }
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx = out_stream->codec;
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            //Find codec encoder
            AVCodec *encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_ctx->codec_id);
            if (!encoder) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
                ret = AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
                goto end;
            }
            //Open encoder
            ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, encoder, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video encoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                goto end;
            }
            out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                out_stream->codec->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
        }
        //Open the decoder for input stream
        codec_ctx = in_stream->codec;
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx,
                avcodec_find_decoder(codec_ctx->codec_id), NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);
    //Open output file for writing
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename);
            goto end;
        }
    }

    //Write video header
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        goto end;
    }
    //Write frames in a loop
    while (1) {
        AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;
        //Read one frame from the input file
        ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];//Get current input stream
        out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];//Get current output stream
        if (pkt.stream_index == videoindex)//video frame
        {
            int got_frame;
            frame = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!frame) {
                ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
                break;
            }
            //Readjust packet timestamp for decoding
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt,
                in_stream->time_base,
                in_stream->codec->time_base);
            //Decode video frame
            int len = avcodec_decode_video2(in_stream->codec, frame, &got_frame, &pkt);
            if (len < 0)
            {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Decoding failed\n");
                break;
            }
            if (got_frame)//Got a decoded video frame
            {
                int64_t pts = av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp(frame);
                //determine if the frame image contains human face
                bool result = faceDetect(frame);
                if (result) //face contained
                {
                    videoTime = pts* av_q2d(out_stream->time_base);
                    frame->pts = videoPts++;//Set pts of video frame
                    AVPacket enc_pkt;
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Encoding video frame\n");
                    //Create packet for encoding
                    enc_pkt.data = NULL;
                    enc_pkt.size = 0;
                    av_init_packet(&enc_pkt);
                    //Encoding frame
                    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(out_stream->codec, &enc_pkt,
                        frame, &got_frame);
                    av_frame_free(&frame);
                    if (!(got_frame))
                        ret = 0;
                    /* Configure encoding properties */
                    enc_pkt.stream_index = videoindex;
                    av_packet_rescale_ts(&enc_pkt,
                        out_stream->codec->time_base,
                        out_stream->time_base);
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Muxing frame\n");
                    /* Write encoded frame */
                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt);
                    if (ret < 0)
                        break;
                }
                else //no face contained
                {
                    //Set the videoTime as maximum double value, 
                    //making the corresponding audio frame not been processed
                    if (videoTime < DBL_MAX)
                        videoTime = DBL_MAX;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
            }
        }
        else//Audio frame
        {
            //Get current frame time
            double audioTime = pkt.pts * av_q2d(in_stream->time_base);
            if (audioTime >= videoTime)
            {//The current frame should be written into output file
                int got_frame;
                frame = av_frame_alloc();
                if (!frame) {
                    ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
                    break;
                }
                //Readjust packet timestamp for decoding
                av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt,
                    in_stream->time_base,
                    in_stream->codec->time_base);
                //Decode audio frame
                int len = avcodec_decode_audio4(in_stream->codec, frame, &got_frame, &pkt);
                if (len < 0)
                {
                    av_frame_free(&frame);
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Decoding failed\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (got_frame)//Got a decoded audio frame
                {
                    //Set pts of audio frame
                    frame->pts = audioPts;
                    audioPts += frame->nb_samples;
                    AVPacket enc_pkt;
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Encoding audio frame");
                    //Create packet for encoding
                    enc_pkt.data = NULL;
                    enc_pkt.size = 0;
                    av_init_packet(&enc_pkt);
                    //Encode audio frame
                    ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(out_stream->codec, &enc_pkt,
                        frame, &got_frame);
                    av_frame_free(&frame);
                    if (!(got_frame))
                        ret = 0;
                    /* Configure encoding properties */
                    enc_pkt.stream_index = audioindex;
                    av_packet_rescale_ts(&enc_pkt,
                        out_stream->codec->time_base,
                        out_stream->time_base);
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Muxing frame\n");
                    /* Write encoded frame */
                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt);
                    if (ret < 0)
                        break;
                }
                else //Shouldn't be written
                {
                    av_frame_free(&frame);
                }
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
    //Write video trailer
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end://Clean up
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Clean up\n");
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        avcodec_close(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec);
        if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > i && ofmt_ctx->streams[i] && ofmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec)
            avcodec_close(ofmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec);
    }
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    /* Close output file */
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF) {
        char buf[256];
        av_strerror(ret, buf, sizeof(buf));
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred:%s\n", buf);
        system("Pause");
        return 1;
    }
    //Program end
    printf("The End.\n");
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code, I have set the `pts` this way.

```
 frame->pts = videoPts++;//Set pts of video frame
```

This means that I assume the `pts` increment between each video frame is 1. But it's actually not the case when I inspected the video stream of the input file under Debug mode, finding that its `pts` increment is 2. After some observation, I found that the `pkt_duration` property of the decoded frame may stands for the `pts` increment in the input video stream because it has the same value with the `pts` increment. So I changed the above code to

```
frame->pts = videoPts += frame->pkt_duration;
```

When I tested the modified code, the video stream and audio stream was not out of sync anymore. So far I cannot ensure that the `pkt_duration` and `pts` increment is actually the same thing, but in my case it seems like that. Anyway, using `pkt_duration` has solved my out-of-sync problem.